# Getting data from one database table into another database table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I imported data from MS-Access into a SQL database using the import/export wizard.
Now, I have database called

TestDatabase - With a Table called AccessTable - It has 10 columns.

on the same SQL Server, I have another database called SampleDatabase with a table called
SampleTable

I want to copy [TESTDATABASE].[dbo].[AccessTable] to [SampleDatabase].[dbo].[SampleTable]

The structure of this table is slightly different. The first two columns don't match but the rest of it match and I want to copy only those matched column.

How to achieve this?

In short: I want 1000 rows from first database insert into second database table.

I am using SQL Server 2008 express for the time being.

Comment: Could you add the schemas of the tables you want copied?

Comment: INSERT INTO SampleTable (col_a, col_b, col_c) SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c FROM AccessTable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run this query:

```
INSERT INTO [SampleDatabase].[dbo].[SampleTable] (
    field1, field2, field3, field4
)
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4
FROM [TESTDATABASE].[dbo].[AccessTable];
```